# Simplest way to validate string (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

I want to check that a string meets the following criteria:

- Consists of exactly two words
- Each word contains only letters (A-Z and a-z), and is at least two letters long
- The two words are separated by exactly one space

For example, "Jon Snow" should validate, and any other name consisting of only one given name and one family name, and no special characters.

What is the simplest way to ensure this validation?

Thanks!

Comment: let us know what you haave tried

Comment: So, you know about regex, but you haven't found the solution? I don't want to disappoint you, but the amount of time required to find the answers to your question at any regex tutorial site is less than you spent on creating the question.

Comment: I have tried looking into regex, but I can't seem to understand it fully. Here is an example of the latest piece of code I've tried:

Comment: @sidgate @user3707125:
Sorry, I can't figure out how to post the code properly here in the comments, but the regex I tried was:
`if (name.matches("([a-zA-Z]) ([a-zA-Z])"))`
but this returns false for "Jon Snow". 
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Note that too broad does not mean too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to o actually. Requirement #1 and #3 are the easiest. To test for whether a string contains two words and are separated by exactly one space, just use the `split` method. For requirement #2, test if the strings have a length that is larger than 2.

Let's say your string to test is called `str`\

```
String str = "Jon Skeet";
```

You can create boolean variables to store the results of each test. It's easier to understand.

```
String[] splitString = str.split(" ");
boolean test1 = splitString.length == 2;
boolean test2 = true;
for (String s : splitString) {
    if s.length() < 2 {
        test2 = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I actually combined the word count test and the "separated by one space" test into one. Because they can be tested simultaneously using one method.

Now you have `test1` and `test2`. You just need to see if they are all `true`:

```
if (test1 && test2) {
    System.out.println("THE STRING IS VALID!");
}
```

You can even extract this as a method:

```
public static boolean isStringValid(String str) {
    String[] splitString = str.split(" ");
    boolean test1 = splitString.length == 2;
    boolean test2 = true;
    for (String s : splitString) {
        if s.length() < 2 {
            test2 = false;
        }
    }

    if (test1 && test2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or you can do the test all in one go, although this is quite hard for people to understand what you are doing.

```
boolean test = splitString.length > 2 && splitString[0].length() >= 2 && splitString[0].length() >= 2;
```

EDIT:

If you want to see if it only contains letters, call `Character.isLetter`.

```
   boolean test2 = true;
   boolean test3 = true;
   for (String s : splitString) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
                test3 = false;
            }
        }
        if (s.length() < 2 && ) {
            test2 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about regex. See my edited code. @iLoveNachos

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely perfect! Worked like a charm, and I fully understood it :-)

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please kindly consider to accept it. Just press the tick below the votes! @iLoveNachos

Comment: The answer was perfect, and I have already marked it as an accepted answer. :-) I gave you an upvote too, but I don't have enough reputation to make it visible yet. Can you see the accepted mark?

Comment: @iLoveNachos  yes I can! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For regular expression part you can try:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+");

        Matcher m = p.matcher("Jon Skeet");
        boolean b = m.matches();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```